# I am getting resource not found when trying to invoke AWS Bedrock agent through python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-bedrock

Below is the error I am getting

> An error occurred (resourceNotFoundException) when calling the
> InvokeAgent operation: Failed to retrieve resource because it doesn't
> exist. Retry the request with a different resource identifier.

Below is how I am calling it.

```
        response = bedrock_runtime_client.invoke_agent(
            agentId="NNVBJK5YNE",
            agentAliasId="TestAlias",
            sessionId=session_id,
            inputText=prompt,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested using `TSTALIASID` in the request to invoke the DRAFT version and got answer from the agent without errors.

```
agentAliasId="TSTALIASID"
```

Reference [documentation on agents test](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/agents-test.html)